# How to select and show all items and the elements inside with the same class in Jquery or Cypress?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-selectors, cypress

I am trying to use jquery to get all elements with class=book.
I tried `$('.store')` and `$('.bookStore .store')` in the dev console tools, but this only returns one element, how do I get all elements with class="store"?

Or am I misunderstanding how selectors on Chrome dev tools works?

Also I am trying to write Cypress tests and I can call
`cy.get(".store").should('have.length', 3)` to get the total length, but I want to see what's elements/attributes are inside, and not the total count.

I'm trying to get all elements with class=store, so I can see what books are in the store. How do we do this or is there a better way? I can't change the html on the page and can only do selectors or what Cypress supports.

Thanks for the help!

```html
<div class="bookStore">
  <div class="store">
     <button class="book">Book A</button>  
     <button class="book">Book B</button>
     <button class="book">Book C</button>
     <button class="book">Book D</button>
     <button class="book">Book E</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="store">
     <button class="book">Fiction Book</button>
     <button class="book">Non-Fiction Book</button>
     <button class="book">Comics</button>
     <button class="book">Manga</button>
     <button class="book">Poetry</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="store">
     <button class="book">Math</button>
     <button class="book">Physics</button>
     <button class="book">Computer Science</button>
     <button class="book">Biology</button>
     <button class="book">Chemistry</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate the stores and the books in each store like this,

```js
cy.get('.store').each(($store, index) => {

  const storeName = 'Store ' + index;

  cy.wrap($store, {log:false}).find('.book', {log:false})
    .then($books => {
      const titles = [...$books].map(book => {
        const available = book.classList.contains('available')
        return `${book.innerText} ${available ? '(Available)' : ''}`
      })
      return `${storeName} has these titles: ${titles.join(', ')}`
    })
    .then(cy.log)
})
```

which will log out

```
Store 0 has these titles: Book A (Available), Book B, Book C, Book D, Book E
Store 1 has these titles: Fiction Book, Non-Fiction Book, Comics, Manga, Poetry
Store 2 has these titles: Math, Physics, Computer Science, Biology, Chemistry
```

Comment: Thank you for the catch and the example! I have updated the html. That looks good. What happens if we have an extra class inside "book" how would we get what the second class is? class="book available" or class="book unavailable" . How do we check if the book is available/ unavailable?

Comment: Ok I think to answer available/unavailable check, I can just change it to .find('.available') to check how many are available, then get the books

Comment: Why do we need to include {log:false}?

Comment: The extra class can be accessed by `.classList` property, but classes should not have spaces. Added in an example.

Comment: `.find('.available')` will limit the output to only those with the extra class, if that's the intention. Be careful of the edge case where there's no `available` class on any book.

Comment: `{ log: false }` just suppresses logging from those commands to give a cleaner output.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean by `class="book available"` - that's two separate classes! Duh!

Comment: Yes two separate classes. Awesome, thank you so much for your help and replies!

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all the elements from the first store section:

```
cy.get('.store').eq(0).find('.book')
```

Similarly, for the second store section, you can use:

```
cy.get('.store').eq(1).find('.book')
```

Get the books for one store:

```
cy.get('.store').eq(0).find('.book').each(($ele) => {
    cy.log($ele.text())
})
```

Get all the books in all stores:

```
cy.get('.book').each(($ele) => {
    cy.log($ele.text())
})
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Would you also know why console.log only shows one result?

Comment: Are you trying to print the names of all the books ?

Comment: Yes, trying to get all the books in a store, or all the stores

Comment: Thank you for the update, clear and concise! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a simple array of all books

```
cy.get('.store')
    .then(elements => {
        let arrayOfBooks = []
        for (const element of elements) {
            cy.get(element)
                .find('.book')
                .each(bookElement => arrayOfBooks.push(bookElement.text()))
        }
        cy.wrap(arrayOfBooks).as('bookList')
    })
```

You can also get an array of store objects by store number and book number

```
cy.get('.store')
    .then(elements => {
        let arrayOfBooks = []
        for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            cy.get(elements[i])
                .find('.book')
                .each((bookElement, bookIndexInStore) => {
                    arrayOfBooks.push({
                        storeNumber: i,
                        bookIndexInStore: bookIndexInStore,
                        bookName: bookElement.text()
                    })
                })
        }
        cy.wrap(arrayOfBooks).as('bookList')
    })
```

And use the value further in the code like this:

```
cy.get('@bookList')
    .then(booklist => {
        //some actions with the bookList
    })
```

Comment: Looks like `cy.get(element)` throws an error

Comment: Maybe you meant `cy.get(elements.get(i))`?

Comment: Edited it to use `cy.wrap`

Comment: The problem is there isn't an `element` in you code.

Comment: Fixed it. Forgot that on the second example I used a normal for loop not for-of loop

Comment: Looks ok, but also your store indexes aren't right - they seem to be the book indexes. (in the final array)

Comment: They come from the for loop. That's why I had made them as distinct names. Of i  found the problem

Comment: Just change `storeNumber: i++,` to `storeNumber: i,` because the loop is doing the `++` part.

Comment: No worries, happy to help.